# debootstrap can't create ubuntu old i386 image for docker

Tags: ubuntu, docker, chroot, schroot

I'm trying to create a docker image with debootstrap.
I'd like to create an ubuntu 8.04 i386 image.
When I run

> sudo debootstrap --verbose --arch=i386 hardy hardy http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/

then

> sudo tar -C hardy -c . | sudo docker import - hardy

It creates the image but when I check the arch inside the container with

> uname -m

it gives me x86_64 and not i386 as I requested before.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

---

### SOLUTION

One way of getting around this problem (see the answer) is
add ENTRYPOINT ["linux32"] to the Dockerfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the architecture comes from the kernel, which comes from the host, not the container. For example, here is the uname output of two very different distribtuions:

```
$ docker run alpine uname -a
Linux 5ef5dac8a8ac 4.1.13-boot2docker #1 SMP Fri Nov 20 19:05:50 UTC 2015 x86_64 Linux
$ docker run debian uname -a
Linux c47f04c71efb 4.1.13-boot2docker #1 SMP Fri Nov 20 19:05:50 UTC 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

They both assume the kernel and architecture of the host. An even better answer than mine: https://superuser.com/a/889474/73766

Answer (score 0):

I copy jpetazzo answer from

https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/611

`uname will always tell you 64 bits. Look at e.g. "file /bin/sh" to see the real arch of the filesystem.`